# How do I use a random forest regression once trained

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest, cart

Similar questions have been asked on these two posts:  [random forest how to use the results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222544/random-forest-how-to-use-the-results) and [How to use random forest for regression after it is trained](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365940/how-to-use-random-forest-for-regression-after-it-is-trained) but I feel like the replies didn't give proper answers.

In python, I was able to use a random forest regression to predict a variable and the test data was quite positive. So now I'm interested in using it for later usages and well… how do I do that exactly?

Unlike a linear regression model where you just get the coefficients and you build a new model with these coefficients, how do you build a new model with the random forest? When I build this new code (that will be use by others), do I have to add the initial training data that I had in order to predict new incoming outputs? It seems a bit silly to do, no?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you have to build a new linear regression model? As long as the model object is somewhere, you can call predict on it. Are you asking how to persist and distribute python objects?

Comment: @Sycorax Yes exactly! I was looking on how this process should be done. So it's related to the language i'm using. I'll check that out. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using sklearn to train the Model, you could use pythons pickle module to save and load the model. 
See [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) for an example.